# Free Publishing Software with layers

Tags: desktop-publishing

I have just tried edraw max again but they still have not fixed it, when I add more and more shapes they start becoming misaligned to the grid, and there is no option I can do about it, 'snap to grid' is enabled.

Also, while it does have layers, layer ordering, hiding & locking, and shape grouping, it is a little confusing because it does not always apply all shapes to a given group or layer despite making sure they are all selected, the groups have no indication as to which one is on the topmost and which one is under that, and so forth. So eventually the program just becomes confused and puts shapes that should be in one layer sort of half in one and half in the other, and then the 'move forward/to front' and 'move backward/to back' buttons no longer work. selecting more than one shape with only a single page and clicking move to page also completely crashes the program.

if you link shapes up with lines you can expand and collapse the root line or any of its sub-lines however when exporting it as a web page, the collapse/expand buttons are no longer clickable, so they do nothing.

I just need something free for windows 10 which lets me draw basic shapes, yet still be able to select them after clicking away, and something which also has layers.

Regards, CC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inkscape

- is free (as in free speech and free beer)
- runs on Windows 10
- lets you draw basic shapes
- lets you reselect a shape after deselecting it
- [has layers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bMcXVe8zIs)